# Spark Streaming and Sockets

Tags: sockets, apache-spark, pyspark, spark-streaming

I have an application that will be streaming data in from an IRC server in Python. Currently, I'm creating a socket object in Python that connects to the IRC server. Before I can receive the data, I send the socket authentication initially and may have to periodically send other messages throughout the streaming process. The problem is, I want to stream the messages in with Spark.

I've read that you can create CustomReceivers to do something like this, but I can't find any information on creating one in Python.

Now, I have two possible solutions that I could implement, both of which I feel are sub-optimal.

1) Create a Python socket that connects to IRC and parse/save the data directly without using Spark.

2) Create a Python socket that connects to IRC, send that data to another local Python socket, and have Spark connect directly to that socket and stream from there.

Am I trying to solve the wrong problem with the wrong tool or is there a way to send data to a socket in Spark, namely, in Python?

Comment: I think making a custom receiver in Scala might be the best option, in addition to switching to Scala.